# Diferença entre as versões do pacote uuid do Python

Tags: python, id

Preciso criar IDs únicos e para isto vou usar o pacote `uuid`. Todavia, na hora de fazer o import fiquei na dúvida sobre qual versão usar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma motivo razoável para ter tantas versões diferentes deste mesmo pacote (5!) na biblioteca padrão do Python?

Comment: Não são implementações aleatórias do Python, são de fato todas as especificações padronizadas de UUID. Cada uma utiliza parâmetros de entrada diferentes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a [Documentação do Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html) se você deseja criar IDs únicos provavelmente deveria utilizar o [uuid1](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid1) ou o [uuid4](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid4) levando em consideração que a primeira opção pode comprometer a privacidade, pois cria um `UUID` contendo o endereço MAC do host, já a segunda cria um `UUID` aleatório.

- uuid1: Realiza a geração a partir do endereço MAC da máquina do host mais uma sentença contendo o numero de sequencia (caso não consiga obter a sequencia, é gerado aleatoriamente um número de 14 bits) e a hora atual
- uuid2: Gera um UUID aleatório.

**Por que não utilizar uuid3 ou uuid5?**

Para criar IDs únicos não é aconselhavel utilizar o [uuid3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid3) e o [uuid5](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid5) pois o primeiro baseia-se no hash MD5 de um identificador de namespace (que é um UUID) e um nome (que é uma string). Já o segundo faz da mesma maneira porém utiliza  o hash SHA-1.

Obs: O `nome` utilizado na geração do `uuid3` e `uuid5` podem ser um domínio, uma URL, uma OID (Objeto de identificação) ou um `X.500DN` ou um formato de saída de texto.